# How scroll screen when picker view appear similarly when keyboard appear?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uipickerview

I have a screen which i shown in image. Now i want that when user click on text filed then a picker view appears. So i want that when picker view appear then view will scroll automatically similarly when keyboard appear. [image: screen]

How do that when picker view appears?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Do you want to scroll the picker view in or scroll the view so that the current question is visible above the picker?

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that you want your app to be in portrait, as you can make the changes if it is landscape. Add a `UIPickerView` to your nib and hook it up to an `IBOutlet`. Then, make a button with an `IBAction` method that animates the `UIPickerView`. Try in the .h file:

```
@interface MyViewController: UIViewController {
  BOOL                    _pickerIsVisible;
  IBOutlet UIPickerView * _picker;
}

- (IBAction)buttonMethod:(UIButton *)aButton;
```

and in your .m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad; {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  _pickerIsVisible = NO;
}

- (IBAction)buttonMethod:(UIButton *)aButton; {
  if(_pickerIsVisible){
    _pickerIsVisible = NO;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f
            animations:^{ 
                CGPoint point = _picker.frame.origin;
                point.y += 216; // The height of the picker.
                _picker.frame.origin = point;
            } 
            completion:^(BOOL finished){
              // Do something here if you want.
            }];
  }
  else{
    _pickerIsVisible = YES;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f
            animations:^{ 
                CGPoint point = _picker.frame.origin;
                point.y -= 216; // The height of the picker.
                _picker.frame.origin = point;
            } 
            completion:^(BOOL finished){
              // Do something here if you want.
            }];
  }
}
```

Make sure you set your `UIPickerView` in the nib to have a y coordinate of 480, so it is below the view.

***Edit:*** If you want the `UIPickerView` to be hooked up and act like the keyboard of a `UITextField` or `UITextView`, you could always hook it up to the `.inputView` property of the `UITextField`, and that would work as well.

Hope that Helps!

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at this great project on gitHub:

https://github.com/reednj/TDSemiModal

It provides a class for making a picker appear like the keyboard, with moving the connected field into view.